# Could someone explain how this terminal command used to find images works?

Tags: terminal, grep, find

I found this command to find all images even if they don't have file extensions. However, I do not know how it works and don't like using things I don't understand

```
find . -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image'
```

Comment: Take a look: https://explainshell.com/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the algorithm is *for each file in the current directory and all its subdirectories, get the file info, look for the word 'image', and print the lines that match*

I'll break the command down into its parts...

```
find . -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image'
```

- `find` - walk a file hierarchy, and list the files
- `.` - start in the current directory
- `-name '*'` - consider all file names
- `-exec file {} \;` - for each file returned by `find`, execute `file` to determine the file type. `{}` is a placeholder for the name returned from `find`
- `|` - pipe the results of the prior command into the next commmand
- `grep` - execute a regular-expression pattern match on each line piped in
- `-o` - short for `--only-matching`; prints only the matching part of the lines
- `-P '^.+: \w+ image'` - look for the specified pattern, which essentially says: *lines that contain the word "image"*. Google "regex cheatsheet" to get a deeper understanding.

You can see the full docs (the manpages) for each individual compnent by running `man find`, `man file`, and `man grep`. The information displayed by https://explainshell.com/ (which @Cyrus mentioned in a comment) comes from the man pages--it's a slick shortcut to finding just the parts you need.

You can also run the commands separately, to experiment: Running `find . -name '*'`, `file <file name>`, and `find . -name '*' -exec file {} \;` will all help to visualize what's happening.